# Connection and upgrade of project with TIA portal v13 sp1

Tags: plc, opc

I have a project built with STEP 7 Basic V13.  I try to use it with STEP 7 Basic V13 SP1 upgrade. But after the load with TIA, when I want to do the connection, I get the error "device not reachable". Sometimes, this error becomes "incompatible device". I am not sure what is happening with the configuration.[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check if the firmware of the selected 1214 CPU matches the one you're using.